# Optimize a string comparison by changing it to 5 int fields or 3 bigint fields?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I am attempting to find a way to optimize a comparison between two SHA1 values in a SQL-Server 2008 R2 database. These are currently 40 character hexadecimal values stored as char(40) within the database. The values are indexed. The list of 'known values' is comprised of 21082054 unique entries. This will be used to compare against data sets that can range in size from under a dozen to billions of entries.

As a software developer I understand that a 40 character string comparison is comparing 40 separate values, one at a time, with an early out option (As soon as they differ, the comparison ends). So the next logical step to change attempt to improve this would seem to be to move the hexadecimal value into containing integer values. This leaves me with 5 32-bit integers or 3 64-bit integers, int and long respectively for most languages these days.

What I am not sure of is how well this line of thinking translates into the SQL-Server 2008 environment. Currently the SHA1 is the Primary Key of the table. To keep that same requirement on the data I would then have to make the primary key 5 or 3 separate fields, build an index on all of those fields and then replicate these changes from the known length table to the unknown length tables.

TL;DR: Will changing a 40 character hexadecimal string into separate integer value fields increase comparison/lookup speed execution?

Comment: Run it on a test DB and see if you can measure a speed difference.

Comment: @cdeszaq That will eventually happen, just have a currently higher priority of something that does not work vs this being cause for concern over execution speed.

Comment: Forgive me. I don't usually bring up grammar issues, but "is comprised of" affects me like nails on a chalkboard. It should either be "comprises" or "is composed of" :-)

Comment: Have you considered using `binary(40)` as the data type? My gut feeling is that using multiple fields will be worse than a single field. I would expect the binary comparison to be the fastest because there is no overhead that might be present for character strings.

Comment: @JeffreySax When I get around to doing some test runs I will definitely add that to the list of things to try out. Thanks! (almost wrote defiantly just to see of MikeDunlavey would notice that one too ;))

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you have to care about that.

A 40-character string comparison is not comparing all 40 characters, unless the first 39 characters are equal.

Nearly all the time it will stop after 1 character.
Most of the rest of the time it will stop after 2.

Comment: Any alternate suggestions on how to improve this comparison by chance?

Comment: @James: As a rule, I wouldn't focus attention on something without actually knowing it accounts for a large enough fraction of time to be a juicy target for optimization. Regarding SQL I generally keep quiet, but the technique *[explained here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/randompausedemo/)* could be adapted to it.